# Retrieve Data from Firestore by Using Cloud Functions HTTP Trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My code is working fine until `db.collection("OrderId").doc("D9XjS3efiV12epxQcgYA").get().then` since it returns "firestoreFunc runnig" when I uncomment the line, but not logging and returns nothing inside `db.collection("OrderId").doc("D9XjS3efiV12epxQcgYA").get().then`.

How can I get access to Firestore using HTTP trigger?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.firestoreFunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>  {
    //return "firestoreFunc running";
    db.collection("OrderId").doc("D9XjS3efiV12epxQcgYA").get().then(snapshot =>  {

        console.log("log : 22");

        return 22;
    }).catch(reason =>  {

    })
});
```

Comment: I can't tell from what you've written exactly what you intend to do with the document you fetched.   Your callable function doesn't return anything to the client (from what you've shown here).  If you do want to return something based on the fetch document, you'll need to handle promises correctly (which you are not here - the function will return before a document is available).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch data from field 'groupId' in the document. I thought it's gonna return 22 (for testing). Can you explain why the function returns before the document is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has to return a promise that resolves with the data you want to send to the client.  As shown now, your function returns nothing, and the document fetch will probably not complete, as the function will be terminated because it doesn't know to wait for the fetch.

Just add a return from the promise returned by get():

```
return db.collection("OrderId").doc("D9XjS3efiV12epxQcgYA").get().then(snapshot =>  {
    console.log("log : 22");
    return 22;
}).catch(reason =>  {
    // you should handle errors here
})
```